# Angular. [HMR] Cannot apply update. Need to do a full reload

Tags: angular, hot-module-replacement

I'm add HMR ([stories configure hmr](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-configure-hmr)) to my Angular project, but instead hot reloading i'm getting it full reload.

Updated to angular 8, the problem is not solved.

```
[HMR] Cannot apply update. Need to do a full reload!
...
[HMR] Error: Aborted because ./node_modules/raw-loader/index.js!./src/app/components/tabs/remark/remark.component.html is not accepted
Update propagation: ./node_modules/raw-loader/index.js!./src/app/components/tabs/remark/remark.component.html -> ./src/app/components/tabs/remark/remark.component.ts -> ./src/app/app.module.ts -> ./src/main.ts -> 0
    at hotApply (http://localhost:4201/runtime.js:525:30)
    at http://localhost:4201/runtime.js:363:22
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4201/polyfills.js:3516:26)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (http://localhost:4201/polyfills.js:3275:43)
    at http://localhost:4201/polyfills.js:4035:34
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4201/polyfills.js:3548:31)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4201/polyfills.js:3320:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:4201/polyfills.js:3726:35)
```

1. List item

Comment: delete the `node_modules` folder and run this command `npm install` and try again.

Comment: this advice didn't help

Comment: did you have lazy loaded modules?

Comment: no I don't use.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I used to run my app like that
`ng serve --hmr`

Once I started using hmr configuration
`ng serve -c hmr`

HMR started working.

You should ensure you have hmr enabled in `angular.json` and `environment.ts`

Comment: It is not helpful at all. I am sure it is impossible to get the error in question by running the `ng serve --hmr`. So, please, edit or remove your answer.