# TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestContent' of undefined. HMR. Angular

Tags: angular, webpack-hmr

I am getting the `[HMR] Cannot apply update. Need to do a full reload!` error in Angular.

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537929/angular-hmr-cannot-apply-update-need-to-do-a-full-reload) has a different issue from mine. You can see the difference by comparing my issue description below.

Here is my stack trace:

[image]

```
[HMR] Cannot apply update. Need to do a full reload!
push../node_modules/webpack/hot/log.js.module.exports @ VM11 vendor.js:554031
(anonymous) @ VM11 vendor.js:553906
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ VM8 polyfills.js:9269
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ VM8 polyfills.js:9028
(anonymous) @ VM8 polyfills.js:9767
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ VM8 polyfills.js:9301
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ VM8 polyfills.js:9073
drainMicroTaskQueue @ VM8 polyfills.js:9479
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ VM8 polyfills.js:9462
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ VM8 polyfills.js:9291
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ VM8 polyfills.js:9116
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ VM8 polyfills.js:9136
scheduleResolveOrReject @ VM8 polyfills.js:9757
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ VM8 polyfills.js:9890
hotUpdateDownloaded @ VM7 runtime.js:362
hotAddUpdateChunk @ VM7 runtime.js:338
webpackHotUpdateCallback @ VM7 runtime.js:57
(anonymous) @ VM751 main.1274ab951088de656961.hot-update.js:1
```

But whenever I click a file in the stack trace I am seeing this:

[image]

The file content says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestContent' of undefined

And hence instead of the HMR I an getting the full page reload. I have done all the steps from [here](https://medium.com/echohub/implementation-of-hmr-hot-module-replacement-to-angular-project-f7bca523bd16) to enable the HMR.

I have checked and the steps did work for a brand new empty project, while in my ongoing project the step are not working. So, there might be something wrong with a setup of my project, but I am not sure what can be wrong and I do not know what I could check.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=723098

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scenario is a Typescript Preact Habitat widget, it takes props from HTML. While developing, HTML props cannot be verified, but I defined the expected type.

Received this error when testing HTML prop without an expected key.

2 options to fix:

- Fix the unverified HTML prop
- Adjust the type to make the attribute optional

Comment: I do not use the `Typescript Preact Habitat` and I am sure that HTML does not have properties, while JavaScript does have properties. Probably you meant HTML attributes?

Comment: yeah, HTML obviously doesn't normally, but habitat is a special library that allows it, for example:
from https://github.com/zouhir/preact-habitat

```<div class="some-class"> <!-- as specified in render, habitat will mount the component in this-->
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "title": "Widget Title passed as prop",
      "theme": "red",
      "anotherProp": "Thanks for trying this widget out!"
    }
  </script>
</div>```

Comment: My point was that maybe your error is similarly from incorrectly assuming the type of a variable that your haven't verified. My plan to avoid this is to maybe the unknown inputs of type ```any``` then to verify their actual type matches what they should be.

Comment: I am grateful for your attempt to help. But you suggestion is not what I was looking for.